# PHP как запустить синхронно работу нескольких функций

Tags: php, yii2

у меня есть код

```
$erros = new Errors();
        $modelCoordinates = new Coordinates();
        $modelBolt = new Bolt();
        $modelBond = new Bond();
        $modelOntaxi = new Ontaxi();
        $modelUgo = new Ugo();
        $modelUber = new Uber();

        if (!empty(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $postCheckResult = $modelCoordinates->checkForTheExistenceOfCoordinates(Yii::$app->request->post());
            if ($postCheckResult === true) {
                $postData = Yii::$app->request->post();
                $uberPrice = $modelUber->getPriceData($postData);
                $boltPrice = $modelBolt->getPriceData($postData);
                $bondPrice = $modelBond->getPriceData($postData);
                $onTaxiPrice = $modelOntaxi->getPriceData($postData);
                $ugoPrice = $modelUgo->getPriceData($postData);

                $arrayPrice = [
                    $uberPrice,
                    $boltPrice,
                    $bondPrice,
                    $onTaxiPrice,
                    $ugoPrice,
                ];

                return $arrayPrice;
            } else {
                return $postCheckResult;
            }
        } else {
            return $erros->returnError('no POST data found','controller');
        }
```

как мне запустить одновременно работу функций(синхронно)

```
$uberPrice = $modelUber->getPriceData($postData);
            $boltPrice = $modelBolt->getPriceData($postData);
            $bondPrice = $modelBond->getPriceData($postData);
            $onTaxiPrice = $modelOntaxi->getPriceData($postData);
            $ugoPrice = $modelUgo->getPriceData($postData);
```

дождался ответа от всех и мог вернуть данные.

пример одной из функций

```
 $erros = new Errors();
        $modelHelpers = new Helpers();

        $jsonDataForPost = $this->createPostData($postData);
        $url = 'https://www.uber.com/api/loadFEEstimates';
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataForPost);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'x-csrf-token: xxxxxxxxxxxx'
            )
        );
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $uberArrayData = json_decode($output);

        if ($uberArrayData->status == "success" AND !empty($uberArrayData)) {
            foreach ($uberArrayData->data->prices as $uberArray) {
                if ($uberArray->vehicleViewDisplayName == 'UberX' OR $uberArray->vehicleViewDisplayName == 'Select' OR $uberArray->vehicleViewDisplayName == 'Green' OR $uberArray->vehicleViewDisplayName == 'Black') {
                    $arrayResultCost[] = [
                        'type' => $modelHelpers->renameUberType($uberArray->vehicleViewDisplayName),
                        'min' => $uberArray->min,
                        'max' => $uberArray->total
                    ];
                }
            }
            $objectCost = $modelHelpers->createObject($this->stdClass, $arrayResultCost, $this::UBER);

            return $objectCost;
        } else {
            return $erros->returnError('uber request API error', self::UBER);
        }
```

Comment: Всё зависит от того, кто у вас такие `$model...`. Если делается запрос через curl, то почитайте вот это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520185/how-to-perform-multiple-guzzle-requests-at-the-same-time

Comment: обновил вопрос, обновил код

Comment: https://andy-blog.ru/ispolzovanie-curl_multi_exec-v-php и я бы рекомендовал использовать guzzle

Comment: Вопрос. Я создаю для CURL обьект, который отправляю в  Curl, как быть с этим? или здесь дождется создания обьекта и затем отправит запросы?